# How to resolve a merge conflict using conflict markers in a single file

Tags: markers, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a merge conflict marked by my source code management system like this. In this case it's quite trivial to resolve it using any editor, but my question is: Which tool can be used to show the "local copy", "common ancestor" and "merged in content" side by side to allow for a more comfortable merge? If there were two or three separate files with the versions, kdiff3, meld, tkdiff or vimdiff would be able to do this, but I haven't found any tool capable of using these quite popular merge conflict markers within a single file.

```
  @Override
  public void clientChanged(Client client) {
<<<<<<< BEGIN MERGE CONFLICT: local copy shown first <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if (votingResult==null) return; // !!! Prüfen, ob nötig
    refresh();
======= COMMON ANCESTOR content follows ============================
    refresh();
======= MERGED IN content follows ==================================
    if (voting!=null) {
      refresh();    
    }
>>>>>>> END MERGE CONFLICT >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  }
```

Comment: I found TkDiff capable of doing it using the option -conflict. https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/